# Android play sound - forceclose error

Tags: android, wav

I am using below code to play wav sound on touch of imageview

```
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ok);
                mp.start();
                while (mp.isPlaying()) { 
                    // donothing 
                 };
                 mp.release();
```

this gives me Force Close error, am i missing anything? or do i need to provide the permission in manifest file?..Please help.

Thanks

Comment: it is very difficult to give advice when you don't provide stacktrace of ur error.

Comment: 10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983): create failed:
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:647)

Comment: 10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:647)
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at samples.demo.MainStart.CombineButton(MainStart.java:438)
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at samples.demo.MainStart.access$0(MainStart.java:378)
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at samples.demo.MainStart$2.onTouch(MainStart.java:274)
10-24 11:03:23.077: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(16983):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3779)

Comment: its throwing java.lang.nullpointerexception

Comment: I guess your MediaPlayer object creation fails. Thus, resulting null in `mp`. When you try to play null object with `start()`, it will throw null pointer exception. Try to make sure your audio/video file in raw folder is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after created media player you have to call prepare() before start. Try this code

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ok);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
```

Comment: thanks for reply... its still throwing same error java.lang.nullpointerexception. is it because try to play-wav on touch of imageview?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this and see.

```
    public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
        //set up MediaPlayer    
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();

}
```

Change this method according to your code. Also if there is any error, you should post the error log so that others could identify the exact issue.

Comment: Its showing java.io.IOException: Prepare failed. You haven't given mp.prepare(). Where is NullPpointerException? I didn't see it in ur log.

Comment: Please debug and see where exactly is the null pointer exception is coming. Check ur imageview, also whether ur raw file is able to read